# Вывод из БД с использованием ООП, PDO и namespace

Tags: php, инспекция-кода

Код работает, правильно ли я всё сделал?
Какие недочёты есть?

**index.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

require_once 'App/db.php';

use App\classes\Db as Db;

$con = new Db();

foreach($con->query() as $key){
    echo $key['id'] . ' ' .$key['name'] . '<br>';
}
```

**db.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\classes;

class Db{
    protected $pdo;
    private $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `books`';

    public function __construct(){
        $this->pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=dz; charset=utf8', 'root', '');
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    public function getSql(){
        return $this->sql;
    }

    public function query(){
        try{
            $result = $this->pdo->query($this->getSql());
            $arrayResult = [];

            while($row = $result->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                array_push($arrayResult, $row);
            }
            return $arrayResult;
        }       
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Правильнее try … catch вытащить в index.php, так как в случае ошибки query() вернет null, и получится ошибка в foreach. В общем нужно придумать как правильнее обрабатывать ошибки

Answer (score -1):

1. Нет контроля успешности подключения к БД в `__construct()`
2. `getSql()` - зачем нужен этот метод?
3. Цикл `while($row = $result->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){...` - вполне можно заменить на `arrayResult = $result->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`
4. Функция `query()` в случае ошибки ничего не возвращает - это плохо. Добавьте в блок `catch` либо возврат пустого массива, либо, например, `false`, чтобы ошибку можно было обработать выше по коду
5. Почему `$pdo` у вам `protected`, а не `private`? Чем это обусловлено?
6. Может и не критично, но подумайте. У вас плохо с переиспользованием установленного соединения. Тут два варианта: использовать persistent connection, либо делать из вашего класса синглтон

Comment: прямо коллекция "вредных советов", которую извиняет только дата написания. Но менее вредной она все равно не становится.

Comment: по пунктам, в 1, 4, и 6 всё с точностью до наоборот. Если за 3 года вы не освоили правильный подход, то можете спросить, я объясню.

Comment: Не путайте "правильный подход" и "подход, который Ипатьев считает правильным" - это несколько разные вещи.

Comment: Ну то вы, к примеру, даже сейчас настаиваете, что  persistent connection -это способ избежать множественных подлкючений в этом коде? И считаете, что убийство сервера БД по too many connections - это "подход, который какой-то Ипатьев считает неправильным"? Мне искренне жаль.

Comment: @Ипатьев вы бы прекращали спорить с голосами в своей голове. Что же касается "в этом коде", то половина ваших советов конкренто к этому коду имеет довольно мало отношения

Answer (score -1):

В целом подход правильный, но есть несколько замечаний

- `private $sql = 'SELECT * FROM books';` здесь **совсем** не на месте. Надо определиться - либо это универсальный класс для работы с БД, но тогда в нем не должно быть никаких запросов в конкретным таблицам. Либо это класс для работы с одной таблицей, но тогда в нем не должно быть соединения с БД.
- если это общий класс для работы с БД, то либо он должен реализовывать 100% функциональности ПДО, либо $pdo должна быть публичной
- никаких catch в коде! Исключения для того и сделаны, чтобы выныривать где-то ещё, а не прямо на месте. Не гоовря уже о том, что **класс для работы с БД не должен выводить ничего на экран**, тем более сообщения об ошибках.
- переменная класса $sql - это совсем неправильно. Класс, который работает только одним запросом к БД - это как-то мелко.
- getSql соответственно, тоже не нужна
- query() **должна поддерживать подготовленные выражения!**
- query() не должна возвращать полученные строки. А вдруг тебе нужно будет исполнить запрос на вставку?
- чтобы не путать с родной функцией PDO::query(), лучше назвать ее как-то по-другому
- вместо унылого бормотания вайл роу равно... в ПДО есть четкая и резкая функия fetchAll()

В итоге, класс Db берем [отсюда](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper#class), а для книжек пишем

```
class BookDB
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct(DB $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function getAll() {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `books`';
        return $this->db->run($sql)->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

Да, и кстати - НИКАКИХ require_once! Осваиваем autoload, чтобы пхп сам грузил наши классы, когда они понадобятся.

Самый простой вариант будет такой.

в корне сайта лежит файл autoload.php с таким примерно кодом

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require __DIR__.'/classes/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.class.php';
});
```

При этом классы лежат в папке classes в корне сайта, в подпапках соотвествующих своим неймспейсам в файлах вида имякласса.class.php:

```
autoload.php
classes/
classes/App/
classes/App/DB.class.php
classes/App/BookDb.class.php
```

после этого ты в своих скриптах подключаешь только один файл autoload.php, а все классы загружаются сами по себе! И в итоге получаем аккуратный код приложения:

```
<?php
require_once 'autoload.php'; // должен быть абсолютный путь

$db = new DB('test', 'user', 'pass');
$bookDb = new BookDb($db);
$books = $bookDb->getAll();
foreach($books as $row){
    echo $row['id'] . ' ' .$row['name'] . '<br>';
}
```

И это будет корректный вывод из БД с использованием ООП, PDO и namespace